# How to make customized top nav bar

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

How to create a top nav bar with the design in the pic i attached below. i want to create a top nav bar like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd use LinearLayout with Horizontal orientation.
Place two TextView object together and then use xml styling to set their background.
Like so:
**activity_main.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
   <LinearLayout
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_background">
    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOn="first_text_view"
        android:textOff="first_text_view"/>
    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOn="second_text_view"
        android:textOff="second_text_view"/>
   </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

**textview_back.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/textview_back_selected" />
    <item android:state_checked="false"  android:drawable="@drawable/textview_back_unselected" />
</selector>
```

**textview_back_selected**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/textview_back_selected" />
    <item android:state_checked="false"  android:drawable="@drawable/textview_back_unselected" />
</selector>
```

**textview_back_unselected**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:width="100dp" android:height="20dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#ddd" android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

**layout_background**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="100dp" android:height="20dp"/>
        <corners android:radius="15dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#dddddd" android:width="1dp"/>
    </shape>
```

this should be the results:
[image]

Hope this is close enough.
Note that you'll have to handle in the mainActivity.java code that once you click 1 button, you need to toggle off the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the material button group

```
  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
            android:id="@+id/groupToggleButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:singleSelection="true">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Male"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Female"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"/>

        </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

java class

```
MaterialButtonToggleGroup materialButtonToggleGroup = 
     findViewById(R.id.groupToggleButton);
```

and you can add a listener on any change of selection

```
materialButtonToggleGroup.addOnButtonCheckedListener(new MaterialButtonToggleGroup.OnButtonCheckedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onButtonChecked(MaterialButtonToggleGroup group, int checkedId, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
      if (checkedId == R.id.button1) {
        //..
      }
    }
```

}
});